# Identity server 4. Identity resource claims in resource owner password flow

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using resource owner password grand type. I implemented 2 interfaces: `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `IProfileService`. When I request a token, I get to the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`, after successful validation I expect `ProfileService` provides me with requested climes. But it never does.

The thing is the `RequestedClaimTypes` from `ProfileDataRequestContext` in the `ProfileService` is always empty, as a result I can't filter out claims which weren't asked.
I expect it contains all claims, which are related to the requested scopes.
For example if I request such scopes as `email` or `"profile"` then I expect claims like `"email"`, `"first_name"`,  `"preferred_username"` and others to be in the `RequestedClaimTypes` list.
There is simple clients and identity resource config:

```
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email()
            };

  ...........................................................................

            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientName = "SomeClient",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 1200,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,

                AccessTokenLifetime = 900,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 120,
                AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
                }
            },
```

Interesting fact is that `RequextedResource` from `ProfileDataRequestContext` has claims data, which I can use to figure out what claims user has requested. For example:

```
            var claimsNames = new List<string>();
            claimsNames.AddRange(context.RequestedResources.IdentityResources.SelectMany(r => r.UserClaims));
            claimsNames.AddRange(context.RequestedResources.ApiResources.SelectMany(r => r.UserClaims));
            context.RequestedClaimTypes = claimsNames;
```

But it seems to be hacky way. Does someone know why `RequestedClaimTypes` isn't populated automatically?

**P.S** Client is the postman with the following parameters
[image]

Comment: What does the client code that calls the token endpoint look like?

Comment: @mackie Please, take a look at the postman request, which I attached as a picture